# Archive Sitecore items using Sitecore PowerShell Extention

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to archive Sitecore items using Sitecore PowerShell. Any commnand that can be used to achieve this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```powershell
# get item to archive
$item = Get-Item -Path '/sitecore/content/ITEM'

# see available archives for current database
[Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager]::GetArchives($item.Database)

# select archive that you want to use
$archive = [Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager]::GetArchive("archive",$item.Database)

# store an item in the archive
$archive.ArchiveItem($item)

# browse archive entries
$archive.GetEntries(0,10)
```

To get more useful function for Archive object see this class
`Sitecore.Data.Archiving.Archive`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archive a particular item version then you need to write your logic like this.

```
# get item to archive and provide the version. Examle 3

$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Uri "sitecore://master/{6151ACBE-40C3-45D5-BCE8-5E939C461C12}?lang=en&ver=3"

[Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager]::GetArchives($item.Database)

$archive = [Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager]::GetArchive("archive", $item.Database)

$archive.ArchiveVersion($item)

$archive.GetEntries(0,10)
```

Now when you go to the Archive window, you will see the version you have archived

[image]